# How to read stdin and write stdout 10k lines fast enough in R language?

Tags: r

The program below just reads pairs of 32 bit integers from stdin and then writes to stdout the absolute difference between them. It's having performance issues. How can I make it run faster?

```r
input <- file('stdin', 'r')
output <- stdout()

while (length(line <- readLines(input, n=1)) > 0) {
    parts2 = strsplit(line, " ")[[1]]
    a = as.numeric(parts2[[1]])
    b = as.numeric(parts2[[2]])
    if (b > a)
        writeLines(paste0(b - a), output)
    else
        writeLines(paste0(a - b), output)
}
```

Context: Sometimes in competitive programming we have to process many thousand of lines in a few seconds. In such cases, many languages such as Clojure, Elixir, R and Julia, will bump into time limit exceeded error, but usually they offer some alternative method of reading stdin and writing to stdout which is much faster. In many cases, the fastest method is through the use of streams.

Note: The online judge won't support any external library. So I'm looking for a native approach.

Note2: I'm using the `number` type because the `integer` type only supports 31 bit integers.

Comment: I really like R for many things it does, but ... speed in stream processing is not really one of its strengths. If you're looking for pure speed, I suggest that R may not be your answer. (FYI, `abs(a - b)` will out-perform `if (b > a) b-a else a-b` every time, though perhaps by an imperceptible difference.)

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it, but perhaps replace `readlines(..)` with `scan(input, what="list")`. One benefit is that it will split the numbers for you, negating the need for `strsplit`, not sure if that's enough to offset any performance difference.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans . After a few tries, I could get the code approved, just under the 4s mark. Scan helped mostly because it allowed me to read the entire input at once. Then I used a for-in loop to iterate the contents. It would be great if there was some way do the same approach in the output. I mean, to accumulate the output lines in a string buffer then write them all to stdout at once.